# Google Apps Script - Date formatting not working

Tags: google-apps-script, timezone, date-formatting

I have the following date `21:50:04 Nov 13, 2017 PST` as String, I'm using the following piece of code to format it (to show only month and day).

```
Utilities.formatDate(new Date(inData[r][0]), "GMT", 'MMM-dd')
```

The output I'm getting is `Nov-14`, I have tried changing the zone to `GMT-05:00` which was still producing the same result.

Can anyone tell me what is the change I have to do so that it will return `Nov-13` for the same input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside the Script editor, go to File > Project properties and ensure that the timezone is set to PST.

Also, since the input is in PST, you should use the same timezone for the output as well.

```
var date = new Date("Nov 13, 2017 21:50:04");
Logger.log(date);
Logger.log(Utilities.formatDate(date, "PST", 'MMM-dd'))
```

Comment: I don't see a choice for PST in the list of available times zones in the scripts property settings.  Just GMT values.

Comment: I meant the Project Properties of the script.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the semicolon in the time zone:

You must use GMT-500

The time zone setting for `Utilities.formatDate()` is very finicky.

Because the time zone of GMT-05:00 is invalid, it resorts back to GMT which is time zone 0000.